# Rational numbers not behaving like fractions in algebra with Ruby

Tags: ruby, math, rational-number

Can someone please explain this to me?

```
x = Rational(3/4) * 8
 => (0/1) # I Expected it to return 6
x.to_i
 => 0
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you want `x = Rational(3, 4) * 8`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a `Rational` number with `3/4` as the only argument. `3/4` is `0`, so, your code is equivalent to

```
Rational(0) * 8
```

which obviously is `0`.

Compare this to

```
Rational(3, 4) * 8
# => (6/1)
```

where you explicitly pass both the numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer having slashes in the fractions, you may use strings as arguments:

```
x = Rational('3/4') * 8
```

or

```
x = ('3/4'.to_r) * 8
```